# How to remove class from other elements in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

my functions toggles the class name on click to an element. But It's not remove the class names from other elements. so all elements are highliting now. But whenever user click on an element, it should have the `classname` rest of siblings has to removed the `classname` how do do this?

here is my try but not works:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    isSelected : false,
    deSelectOthers : function(){
        this.set( "isSelected", false ); //deselecting all before add the class to clicked element
    },

    actions : {
        selectCard : function(card) {
            this.deSelectOthers(); //de select others not works
            this.toggleProperty('isSelected'); // add class to this element only works. how to remove class from other element?
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
I am sorry for bad description about my requirement. I have created the requirement using `jQuery` - simply how to achive the same with `emberjs`?
[Demo-Requirement](https://jsfiddle.net/uw5vvrr9/)

Comment: Please provide [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com) since its missing important code to identify the issue

Comment: Leave my code, can you show me a way to do?

Comment: Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464122/5771666) it looks like its matching your requirement...its written 3 hours ago !!

Comment: I had no toggle class, it just adding a class. I need to toggle class

Comment: You're going to need to clarify this question.

Comment: @sheriffderek - updated the question. added the demo from jquery

Comment: Appreciated your jsfiddle :)

Comment: @sheriffderek - by the how to add the `action` event to component and pass to component `action`. i try like this `<ul>
  {{#each cardList as |card|}}
   {{
    cs2i-cardcomponent 
    card=card 
    enableNext='enableNext' 
    tagName='li'
    action=("selectCard card ")
   }} 
  {{/each}}
 </ul>` but not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/915ac6406df17e964db78dc5dca0fe2a?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

You need to maintain selectedIndex/value and use if check to update class based on the selectedIndex/value.

application.hbs

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
  {{#each model as | temp index|}}
    <li class={{if (eq selectedIndex index) 'highlight' }} {{action 'changeSelectedIndex' index}}>{{temp}}</li>
 {{/each}}   
  </ul>
</div>
```

routes/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return [1,2,3,4];
  }
});
```

controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({  
  selectedIndex:undefined,
  actions:{
    changeSelectedIndex(index){
      this.set('selectedIndex',index);
    }
  }
});
```

You need to install ember-truth-helpers addon by running `ember install ember-truth-helpers`

Comment: You are correct. But in case of component this logic not working. unless if i am not re-click the component the class not removes

Comment: check [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1cff08ba77b6b8f50928e4d060f30123?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) implmented in comonent.

Comment: can you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481246/ember-component-how-to-add-border-to-only-on-click-component