# Ember-Component how to add border to only on `click` component?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to highlight the `component` on `click` event.( need to add a class name as `addBorder`) how to do that? while user clicks on other component, I would require to remove `addBorder` from other components.

so only the `click` componet will be highlighted at once.

I can do using `jQuery` very easily but I am looking for `ember` way!!

here is my demo: [Live Demo Link](https://ember-twiddle.com/28d479172340f7ee1acf4cbcda67b64c?openFiles=styles.app.css%2Ctemplates.components.my-child.hbs)

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/4eaf4c8d3ab83e027e4e24db280c774d?openFiles=templates.components.my-parent.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-child.hbs

Comment: if user clicks back the same element how to remove the class( toggle class)

Comment: In `changeSeletectedIndex` function , just check for existing selectedIndex and clicked index is same then make it selectedIndex as empty...Nothing special in ember, after all its javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add property like `selectedItemTitle` which will be changed on  `click` to `item.title`. Then you can pass this `selectedItemTitle` down to components. Component can check if its `item.title === selectedItemTitle`. If yes then property like `isSelected` can be set to true. Then you bind `isSelected` to a class using `classNameBindings`.

Parent component template:

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
    {{my-child item=item.title info=item.info tagName="li" selectedItemTitle=selectedItemTitle click=(action 'selectItem' item.title)
    }}
{{/each}}
```

See [working demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/b50170a742d4a3a9ad8027fad0067ee6?openFiles=components.my-parent.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-child.hbs).

Comment: Live demo not working, can you please look in to it? ( on click list do nothing)

Comment: Sure. Give me one second.

Comment: Please try now. :)

Comment: Is this the correct ember way? because I would like to stick with ember guidelines

Comment: Yes, definitely. We haven't used any jQuery. We've used data-down actions-up concept and a closure actions. This is definitely Ember way!